# Can someone explain why I keep getting these errors in Flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I keep getting these errors in my Flask app:

- malloc(): unsorted double linked list corrupted
- double free or corruption (!prev)

basically I'm calling the pos() method and trying to get the year attribute from my JS page in order to use it in my query... but it doesn't work and instead returns some malloc error

can someone explain the problem and how to solve it???? I've been at it for hours of research and I still don't understand how my code is generating these errors. If someone could just point me in the right direction and give me a hint, I would really appreciate it. I looked into similar malloc errors on many different posts, but I tried the solutions they proposed (adding command: [
'--wait_timeout=28800',
'--max_allowed_packet=67108864'] to my docker-compose file)
did NOT work.

```
yr = 2022
pos_list = []

def pos_request():
    global yr
    global pos_list
    cursor1 = conn.cursor (cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) ##conn is already set up
    query = “private database structure info that I can’t share“ % (yr, yr, yr)
    try:
        cursor1.execute (query)
        pos_list = []
        for r in cursor1.fetchall():
            pos_list.append (r)
        cursor1.close ()
        return pos_list
    except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
        return e

@app.route('/pos', methods= ['POST'])
def pos():
    global yr
    try:
        yr = int(request.json['year'])
        return json.dumps(pos_request(), default= str)
    except:
        return yr

@app.route('/pos', methods= ['GET'])
def pos_get():
    return json.dumps(pos_list, default= str)

@app.route('/pos_post', methods = ['POST'])
def pos_post():
```

Comment: Try using a pure-python database driver like pymysql.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong. MySQLdb simply isn't built to support multiple cursors using one MySQL connection. I got this from their site: "Two threads simply cannot share a connection while a transaction is in progress, in addition to not being able to share it during query execution." So the only way is to use another class, like the pymysql driver snakecharmerb suggested. Or, if you can, open new MySQL connections for each method/route.

Sources:
https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html     (scroll down to threadsafety)